# send notification from firebase console to old users with gcm tokens?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I have questions about migrating from gcm to fcm.
we are going to migrate from gcm to fcm. we have lots of users with gcm tokens and we have already sent them push notifications from onesignal panel. now when we migrate to fcm,what happens to old users with gcm tokens? I know if we force our users to update their android version to new version(the one with fcm) the new fcm token will be generated for users. but what if we don't want to force our users to update? Is it possible to send notification from firebase console to old users that have gcm tokens?

I have already done the migration procedure according to this link:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Comment: AFAIK, the [GCM tokens should still work when sending using the FCM endpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42337465/4625829). Although I haven't tried doing it from the Firebase Console, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Make sure the Google Play Services Version to be greater than 29 and Google Repository Version to be greater than 28

Answer (score 1):

I tried same but gcm people is not getting notification so i make 2 payload 1 for fcm and 1 for gcm and sending massage for both fcm and gcm at same time so i m getting gcm notification but you have to handle crash for gcm notification in fire-base  app. means it will crash when you receive gcm notification on fcm but when fcm notification come it will diaplay