# MismatchSenderID error in firebase API

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing **server-side code** for android notification using **FCM**.

So the code sends the notification correctly to the topics but not to the particular device's registration token. 
*So the code works fine for this case-*

```
info.put("to", "topics/xyz"); 
info.put("title", "Hello 1");
info.put("body", "Hi");
```

But for the second case-

```
info.put("to", DeviceIdKey.trim()); //device registration token
info.put("title", "Hello 1");
info.put("body", "Hi");
```

it gives,

**OUTPUT**:

```
{
"multicast_id": 1XXXXXXX01820YYYY2,
"success": 0,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
        {
            "error": "MismatchSenderId"
        }
    ]
}
```

**IMPORTANT** - And the registration tokens for all the android/IOS devices which I have are 2 years old generated by GCM. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`MismatchSenderId`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) error occurs if your target token is not associated to the project that is sending the message (as I mentioned in my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43912791/4625829) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43244992/4625829)). It **does not** mean that the token is expired, if it were, you would receive a `NotRegistered` error instead.

In general, GCM tokens should still be compatible with FCM (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43017737/4625829)), they could still receive the message, provided that the sender is associated with the token (if you simply ***import*** your project to Firebase Console, then it should be fine).