# Converting/migrating from GCM to FCM for push notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I migrate my current GCM configuration to FCM what will happen to all the users of my Android app? Will I have to force all users to update or will the APK continue working as it is?

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply referring to import your GCM project to Firebase, you should still be able to send messages to your users with GCM implemented apps (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43017737/4625829)).

For migrating the app implementation from GCM to FCM, you don't necessarily have to force an update with the users. As I mentioned above, GCM is still compatible with FCM, so there's no need to worry about it. It's just advisable to migrate the implementation. As per the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq):

> **How different is GCM from FCM? What is new in FCM SDKs?**
>
> FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure to make sure we continue to deliver messages reliably on Android, iOS and Chrome.
>
> The new FCM SDK:
>
> 1. Simplifies client development. You no longer have to write your own registration or subscription retry logic.
> 2. Enables a new serverless notifications solution with a web console, Firebase Notifications. With Firebase Notifications, anyone can send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase Analytics insights. They can then evaluate notification effectiveness by assessing the built-in Notifications Funnel Analysis in the console.
>
> FCM Android and iOS SDKs make messaging and notifications development easier. They offer an out-of-the-box solution so that anyone can send notifications from Firebase Notifications immediately.