# I am going to import my old GCM project to Firebase. Will this operation remove my old GCM project?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am going to import my **old GCM** project to Firebase. Will this operation remove my old GCM project? 
Bothering about **old users who are using previous mobile app version** with GCM pushes.

In documentation this process explined simple:

"How do I add Firebase to an existing Google project?
You may have existing projects managed through the Google Cloud console or the Google APIs console. By default, these projects are visible in the Firebase console, but are not considered to be Firebase projects.
To add Firebase to your existing project, click "Import Google Project" on the Firebase console landing page."

Please anyone just give me  ))) and say that users **will be alive** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting/migrating from GCM to FCM for push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44392103/4625829)

Answer (score 0):

This is something I am working on as well. I was trying to ensure that there would be backward compatibility. Google says there is but I did not want to blindly rely on this. I tried to set up a GCM version of client and connect  it to the FCM project and send downstream messages. This has not been successfully for me! This is a concern for us to update!