# Create FCM app of existent GCM app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an old Android app, developed on eclipse, that use GCM for receive push messages (and a custom server that use GCM too for send push messages to app). Now i need to pass code on Android studio, so i need to keep GCM for push messaging (i'll upgrade to FCM later).
Now as i can read on GCM tutorial, i need to create an app on Firebase console and do few steps for use it on my Android app. 
If i do it without update also my custom push server code, does both old and new app will continue receive push messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to older clients when you migrate an app server from GCM to FCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016683/what-happens-to-older-clients-when-you-migrate-an-app-server-from-gcm-to-fcm)

Comment: If you're using the same project the tokens are associated with to send the messages, then the old clients should be able to receive the messages as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow official migration from [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)
The gcm/fcm server endpoints are changed as(change the server code according to)

```
gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/ to  fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/
gcm-xmpp.googleapis.com to fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com
```

You can also see in the guide that

> Updating these endpoints is not strictly required, as Google will
>   continue to support the existing GCM endpoints.