# How to get new token when migrate from GCM to FCM for existing app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have application with GCM it's working fine,now i want to migrate from GCM to FCM.

I have used [this](http://%20https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) document for migration,everything working fine for **new installed apk**.It call the `onTokenRefresh` and i have used that token for future use.

**Issue is**

When i **update** new app(**have FCM code**) on existing app(**have GCM code**).it will not call `onTokenRefresh` method.So how can i upload new token on server for future use when apk is updated  not a fresh installed.

In this case i have also tried `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` it but provide a new token but `onTokenRefresh` not get executed.

Can any one provide a solution for this,how to identify app get updated from GCM to FCM so i will upload new token on server.

Comment: It doesnt execute because the existing tokens still work. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43017737/4625829

Comment: @AL. is it means that if i changed URL from https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send to  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send on server for sent notification still it work for GCM token also?

Comment: Yes. The FCM API is backwards compatible.