# Will Firebase FCM keep sending Push Notification to old GCM's tokens after migration?

Tags: cordova, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to ask for help to understand how works this migration from GCM to FCM, in an app that already is published in Android and Apple Stores..

We have one App in Cordova that uses GCM and APN to send Push Notification. Recently we was forced to upgrade out plugins and one of them was the Push Plugin. The problem is that the plugins now are working just with Firebase and we upgraded our GCM and APN to Firebase. Now, my new app version just have Firebase and my server will just send pushes to Firebase.

I already know that part of my users probably will not update to the app new version, or will take some time to do it, but I cannot stop to send pushes to all of them (users with GCM app version and FCM app new version).

**So, my Question is:** When I chenge add Firebase to my Google project and start to send pushes just to Firebase (from my web CMS), my old users with GCM app version will keep receiving my pushes or it will no longer work?

Are the old tokens automatically migrated do FCM and I don't need to worry about nothing or do I need to do something else?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating GCM to FCM, should/could I keep my current GCM server side of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672486/migrating-gcm-to-fcm-should-could-i-keep-my-current-gcm-server-side-of-code)