# What intent actions are received when a message is sent?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I send a message from a Firebase enabled project, which intent actions get fired?

My Manifest is as follows:

```
<receiver android:name="com.test.testapi.MyPushReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <category android:name="com.test.androidtester" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<service
        android:name="com.test.testapi.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I see that `MyFirebaseMessagingService` gets called as expected, however I also see that `MyPushReceiver` gets called with the `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` intent action.

Is it guaranteed that `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` will continue to get called with Firebase? Perhaps Google kept this functionality in the interim until GCM becomes fully deprecated.

*Note: Ideally I would like to keep the existing `MyPushReceiver` in my Manifest for backward compatibility with numerous apps that I support that could be on either FCM or GCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just expected behavior. Since even when using FCM to send the messages, devices/app instances that still have GCM implementations would still be able to receive the messages.

[It's just compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337465/4625829). You don't really have to implement two separate services just to make sure that the app is compatible with both GCM and FCM.

There's actually no way to tell if *it is guaranteed* (not for me at the very least), but I guess it's safe to say that they will continue to be *compatible* until such time that Google decides to deprecate it completely.